# Ionic 3 CLI unable to start project behind proxy

Tags: ionic3, ionic-cli

I'm new to Ionic. I'm facing proxy issues while getting started with Ionic 3.

After installing Ionic & cordova via npm tried to create a new project with the below command as suggested by ionic help
[image]

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
```

followed by

```
ionic start helloWorld blank --type ionic-angular
```

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443[image]

npm config and git config are already set and working since i work with angular behind proxy able to install any libraries and push to github without any issues

- npm config set proxy http://userid:password@proxy.server.com:port
- npm config set https-proxy  http://userid:password@proxy.server.com:port
- npm config set http-proxy  http://userid:password@proxy.server.com:port
- git config --global http.proxy
  http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080

Having environment variables HTTP_PROX,PROXY and IONIC_HTTP_PROXY as well.

Tried uninstalling ionic and reinstall, set proxies again but nothing helps. Couldn't find any help.Do i need to set any other proxy to work with ionic 3 ? 
Kindly guide me in resolving this.

**versions**

- Node : 7.8.0
- npm : 4.0.3
- ionic : 3.1.2
- cordova : 7.0.1

Comment: are you sure env variables are set correctly? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#using-a-proxy

Comment: Thanks for the link Suraj , I have added IONIC_HTTP_PROXY as well but still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Yoda Is your problem fixed? If yes, please share ..thanks

Comment: @mnhmilu No ! problem still exists.Have raised a issue but no solution yet.  You can also confirm the issue there [Ionic 3 CLI unable to start project behind proxy](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/2317)

Comment: Having same issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem with ionic 3 
it solved by use latest versions of node.js

in fact I used versions v6.10.3 recommended for most user, don't use the current versions, because normally it doesn't not stable yet.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed after updating to latest CLI 3.3.0

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.3.0
Ionic CLI               : 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : Windows 7
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```